# Ajax POST Request not working in Spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to post XML data by using AJAX POST Request.

Here is Ajax request:

```
$("#btnSubmitEdit").click(
    function(event) {
        $(document.body).css({"pointer-events": "none", "cursor": "wait"});
        var reqMsgId = $("#msgID").val();
        var reqMsg = $("#xmlMessage").val();
        $.ajax({
            url : "update/" + reqMsgId,
            data:{reqMsg: encodeURIComponent(reqMsg)},
            type : "POST",
            success : function(data) {                                               
                $(document.body).css({"pointer-events": "", "cursor": "default"});
            },
            error : function(e) {                                                
                $(document.body).css({"pointer-events": "", "cursor": "default"});
                alert("Error" + e.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update/{reqMsgId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String updatePage(@PathVariable("reqMsgId") String reqMsgId, @RequestParam("reqMsg") String reqMsg) {
    System.out.println(reqMsg);
    esbresubmitmessageservice.updateMessage(reqMsg, Integer.parseInt(reqMsgId));
    return "success";
}
```

Error:

> Nov 15, 2016 8:41:37 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound
>   noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/Appname/403] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>Appname</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

ApplicationContext

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.appname" />
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@*****" />
    <property name="username" value="*****" />
    <property name="password" value="*****" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:persistenceUnitName="MonitorJpaPersistenceUnit" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: Can you also post if there is any @RequestMapping at controller level and also the web.xml

Comment: Just i have added web.xml.

Comment: Just wondering where the uri /Appname came from

Comment: That is app name. you can see that in web.xml

Comment: The URI in the exception says "/Appname/403" .. it ahould have been "/Appname/update/403" . I guess. You need to check in your browser developer console the requested url .

Comment: can you show your applicationContext

Comment: I have added applicationContext.

Comment: Can you change your AJAX url from  "update/" + reqMsgId", to   "/update/" + reqMsgId,

Comment: Saying requested resource is not available.